# How to loop and print all the values for each key in string for json?

Tags: python, json, string

```
m = [{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":0},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":1},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":2},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":3},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":4},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":5}]
```

I would like to print all the values for "id". From 0 -5. Then make changes into it to become 6-11. And then the new value append it to the old one and save the file. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    yes it is passible to php see below example     



   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <?php 


    $m=[   ["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>0],
           ["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"b","id"=>1],
            ["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"c","id"=>2],
           ["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"d","id"=>3],
            ["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"e","id"=>4],
              ["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"f","id"=>5]
           ];


      //echo gettype($m)."<br>";
      $myJSON = json_encode($m);
     //echo $myJSON;
      $myJSON=json_decode($myJSON);
    echo "<table border='2px'><tr><th>Text</th><th>Speeker</th><th>ID</th></tr>";
     foreach($myJSON as $a)
     {
     echo"<tr><td>". $a->text."</td><td>".$a->speaker."</td><td>".$a->id."</td> 
        </tr>";
   } 
   echo "</table>"; 



     //add the id 6 - 11
      array_push($m,["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>6]);
      array_push($m,["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>7]);
      array_push($m,["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>8]);
      array_push($m,["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>9]);
      array_push($m,["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>10]);
      array_push($m,["text"=>"mamamia","speaker"=>"a","id"=>11]);
       //print_r($m);

       $myJSON = json_encode($m);
          //echo $myJSON."<br>";
                 $myJSON=json_decode($myJSON);
          echo "<table border='2px'><tr><th>Text</th><th>Speeker</th><th>ID</th> 
     </tr>";
        foreach($myJSON as $a)
         {
         //print_r($a);
            echo"<tr><td>". $a->text."</td><td>".$a->speaker."</td><td>".$a->id." 
      </td></tr>";
  } 
   echo "</table>"; 


     ?>
     </body>
     </html>

            **output**

           [Output we get]


     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU9k7.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m.map(function(obj) {
console.log(obj.id);
obj.id = obj.id + 6;
})
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in python sir?

Comment: ofcourse you can use this in python. see the doc for python map syntax.

http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: I made it. Thank you sir

Comment: Is it possible to replace it to the original file sir?

Comment: Can you assist me in replacing the new values into the list to become like [{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":1},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":2},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":3},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":4},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":5},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":6}]

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: also paste the new value you got

Comment: I wish to make the current 0-5 values in the "id" to 6-11. Instead of just showing 0-5 I wanted to write it in python to have the json file replace to new values(6-11).
[{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":6},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":7},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":8},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":9},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":10},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":11}]

Answer (score 0):

Because it is **json string** i would prefer to work with it as **deserialized object** like this:

```
string = '[{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":0},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":1},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":2},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":3},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":4},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":5}]'

deserialized = json.loads(string)
for obj in deserialized:
    obj["id"] = obj.get("id") + 6

print(json.dumps(deserialized))
```

Output:

```
[{"id": 6, "text": "mamamia", "speaker": ""}, {"id": 7, "text": "mamamia", "speaker": ""}, {"id": 8, "text": "mamamia", "speaker": ""}, {"id": 9, "text": "mamamia", "speaker": ""}, {"id": 10, "text": "mamamia", "speaker": ""}, {"id": 11, "text": "mamamia", "speaker": ""}]
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, this is what I prefer it to be.

Comment: But can you tell me also, how can I replace all the new values into the json file to have this? [{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":1},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":2},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":3},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":4},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":5},{"text":"mamamia","speaker":"","id":6}]

Comment: So you dont want to update values but you want to copy whole record with new value?

Comment: I want to update the values to new values that is in increment of +1. Is it possible?

Comment: @Joe +1? I think you said you want 0 to become 6, etc. You can just simple change constant in code.

Comment: Yea, I am ok with any increment as I just want to know how to increase it and then replace the old with new values and print the whole file with new values. Is it possible?

Comment: @Joe Thats what my code already do. You have also the printed output of script in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt realize that the print is actually with .dump. Thank you

Comment: @Joe You have to serialize object back to string ;)